# multicols package set column width

Tags: margins, multicol, geometry

Iam having trouble making my text evenly distribute over the entire width of the page

```
\oddsidemargin -0.3in
\evensidemargin -0.3in
\textwidth 7.3in
\textheight 9in

\begin{multicols}{2}

my text

\end{multicols}
```

my right side margin is larger than left margin.

Comment: multicol is setting its column width based on the available space offered, i.e., it is not changing the width of the margins on either side but simply takes the current \linewidth and divides it into columns and column-separators. So what you want to achieve has to be done on a different level as explained inthe answers and has nothing to do with multicols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\oddsidemargin` is used on odd numbered pages and `\evensidemargin` is used on even numbered pages; neither of those is directly setting the right margin.  To center your text with a `\textwidth` equal to 7.3 inches on paper that's 8.5inches wide, you should use

```
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.4in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.4in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7.3in}
```

That sets the left margin to be 1 inch minus 0.4 inches, which is 0.6 inches.  That 0.6 inches plus 7.3 inches for text leaves you a right margin of 0.6 inches.

Comment: i did this but the text doesnt seem to stretch to the width ?how can i change the column text width as well ?

Comment: @user5535: I just tested it, using only `\documentclass{article}`, followed by those setlength commands, followed by `\begin{document}`, followed by paragraphs of text, followed by `\end{document}`; it works for me.  If it doesn't seem centered to you, perhaps try `latex testpage.tex` to print a testpage and see if that comes out centered.

Answer (score 5):

Margins are best managed with **geometry**

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper,textwidth=7.3in,hmarginratio=1:1,
  textheight=9in,vmarginratio=1:1,heightrounded}
```